# Code for login gone wrong

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, authentication

I am having problem logging in, below is a login code. When I submit login info it says Incorrect Information, I have gone wrong somewhere in code and can't figure it out. I have used `password_hash()` function, checked my database and it works well. Surely somethings wrong with login code. Now I tried `echo`ing  `$pass_db` and on submitting info I see the password is echoed correctly but incorrect information is also displayed and I am not redirected to `main.php` as I should be.

`login.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
$username = $_POST['user_login'];
$password = $_POST['password_login'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM userss WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':password'=>$password));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$user_db = $row['username'];
$pass_db = $row['password'];

if(password_verify($password, $pass_db))  {  
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
  setcookie('username', $username,time()+31556926);
 }
   header("Location:main.php");

 }
 else {
 echo "Incorrect Information!";
 }
 }
 ?>
```

register code

```
$pswd = password_hash($pswd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pswd2 = password_hash($pswd2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userss (username,first_name,last_name,email,password,password2) VALUES (:username,:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password,:password2,)");  
$stmt->execute( array(':username'=>$un,':first_name'=>$fn,':last_name'=>$ln,':email'=>$em,':password'=>$pswd,':password2'=>$pswd2));

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
header("Location: login.php");
} 
else {
echo "error";
}
```

Comment: You need to remove password from the query. If you're using password_verify properly then the password is stored hashed in the DB. Atm you are trying to fetch a user where password "abc123" = "$2a$12$TR22HKzAQwmmUjZ1jdaei.1RyusGqxbPl2aJHvcCwM/V57t67rIcy", so you're never going to get a matching user.

Comment: @JimL still same, I updated some registration code in my question, may be problem is using password and confirm password in registration form?

Comment: note sure why you need to store two passwords, but the answer below by Saty should fix this for you.